# Solidity compiler and Deploy & run transactions buttons are missing in Remix

Tags: remix

Solidity compiler and Deploy & run transactions buttons are missing in Remix.

I tried many times to refresh with no result.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to activate the plugin first. Go to the plugins tab (second icon in the menu on your screenshot), under "Inactive Modules" search for "Solidity compiler" and "Deploy & run transaction" and activate them. Then the other tabs should show up in the menu bar.